# Balancing server bandwith

Tags: linux, nginx, unix, bandwidth, lighttpd

I am working on a file uploading website.

It will be run on dedicated server with 1GBPS connection.

I wanna offer visitors max download speed possible at the current moment.

So lets say server can produce 100mb/s for downloads.
If there are 10 users downloading files at same time I would limit each user to 10mb/s, if 100 to 1mb/s, and so on.

I found this solution, but its not dynamical.
http://www.nginxtips.com/how-to-limit-nginx-download-speed/

Any tips?

Comment: Have you considering using a service for file uploads, like uploading straight to AWS's S3?

Comment: It's too expensive for file storage